# Porting Qt3 to a different OS

Tags: qt, porting

I have to port the application which is using the Qt3 library to a new embedded OS. 
If the OS is not yet selected but it is known that it is not Linux/Windows, what is the general way of porting procedure? I mean what files should be changed and what are independed and can be left as is?

Comment: If the new OS isn't known, how do you know Qt even supports it?

Comment: The OS will have GUI support and threads etc. I think the Qt has part of code independent of the OS and part of it is dependent, and can be customized for linux or windows. But is there a guide for setting up OS API for non linux/windows OS, this is the question.

Comment: First of all you should port your application to Qt4. You will surely encounter many problems caused with Qt3 being almost dead

Comment: Thanks! I will try to port it to Qt4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not Linux or Windows you could be pretty stuck out the door. Qt is highly dependent on libraries being available for it to be able to build. This is not a no however, it has been ported to Symbian which is obviously not Linux or Windows. The big thing on that though is that it was ported by Nokia, who had  amount of time and  amount of developers, where those X's are reasonably big numbers.

Start by getting the Qt everywhere source code, work out what bits you're going to need and which bits you won't. If the platform has gcc/g++/another reasonably well understood C++ compiler you're in luck and you should be able to build the bits as needed. Qt does depend on standard libraries throughout so make sure they're also available in some form for the platform, and it does use some non-standard ones for some components so you'll need to know which aspects of Qt you're working on. You should be able to get some sort of toolchain from there.

I'd stick to platforms that Qt supports though, if you go off the beaten track you're looking into increasing your dev times and having very little useful support.